# Is this true about low-light/one photon at-a-time double-slit interference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons, double-slit-experiment, interference

I've consistently noticed in pictures of double-slit interference when very low-light or one photon at-a-time is used, that there's lots of "stray" photons detected in the areas of destructive interference.  That is to say, the pattern still emerges, but less "cleanly" than one might expect.

On the other hand, from all the representations I've seen, it's my understanding that in the original "normal intensity light" version of the double-slit, the areas of destructive interference can be made to at least appear completely devoid of light.

I'm aware that the difference might have an easy explanation if it's true. But that's my question...is it true? Have you noticed the difference that I speak of, or am I just imagining things?

Comment: It's important to note that in an intensity modulation such as $I\propto \cos^2(x)$ there are only infinitesimally-thin (i.e. of measure zero) points where the intensity is actually zero, so every region of nonzero measure is susceptible of getting at least some hits.

Comment: You are probably not so much imagining things as that these experiments aren't really being carried out cleanly. To be very honest with you, physics proper doesn't care much about the double slit experiment. It is by its very nature not a precision test of quantum mechanics and it can't be made into one. The precision tests are almost universally either measuring the frequency/wavelength of an atomic or nuclear transition, the behavior of spin systems or are based on symmetry considerations, which predict the observed energy eigenstates of a system.

Comment: @CuriousOne, you say that physics proper doesn't care much about the double-slit experiment. But I think you mean quantum physics in particular, and I see it as the opposite. That the double-slit experiment, and other similar effects of light, are for quantum physics an enormous burden. Quantum physics can't shake 'em off, and boy does it hate it. Especially the double-slit using one photon at-a-time, it's like quantum physics' kryptonite.

Comment: Quantum mechanics is not a person. It's a theory. If you know how it works, then you know why the double slit experiment is merely a triviality and if you don't, then you may imagine all kinds of magical kingdoms and sky castles around it. It sounds like you are still at the stage where you are seeing magic where there is none. No, the world is not classical but it is quantum mechanical... so what? So nothing. Absolutely nobody who does physics professionally gets excited about that, it's just part of the craft.

Comment: That sounds to me a little like wishful thinking.

Answer (score 2):

The key is in your words "to ... appear".   I believe that it's a perceptual issue with how your brain processes the two kinds of images:  a smooth rendering or a pixelated rendering.

There is another possibility.  In order to be sensitive to single photons, the detector is also going to be sensitive to very low-level noise.  An image taken with a bright source won't have that problem; the signal of interest would overwhelm the noise.

I rather believe that the issue is perceptual, but either way the effect does not contradict our understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @garpy, that was an excellent answer (yes, I up-voted it).

Comment: It's an issue of contrast; in the classical wave experiment there is plenty of data, and the contrast between the peaks and valleys is very clear; but when you are counting one-by-one the pixelation remains obvious.  In my electron diffraction experiments the contrast became comparable when the aggregate electron counts were similar: short exposure times for a large number of electrons per pulse, vs long exposure times when there were only a few electrons per pulse.  The same applies for photons, IMHO.

Comment: @garyp, I like your answer, and I too think that something along those lines may be the case. For it only needs to be remembered that, with the very low light/one photon at-a-time setup, it's always a CCD recording where the light lands, so that the pattern we see built up is made up of recorded moments that, unrecorded, wouldn't have amounted to anything even visible. Whereas in the original "full light" set up, what we're seeing is the constant and manifold bombardment of the back plate with light in real time. On the other hand, you didn't actually answer my question, lol.

Comment: @Peter Diehr, although it's not what I wanted to hear, what you're saying answers my question directly. May I request that you elaborate your comment as an answer?

Comment: @DavidReishi: If I have time tomorrow evening, I'll include some images.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue of contrast; in the classical wave experiment there is plenty of data, and the contrast between the peaks and valleys is very clear; but when you are counting one-by-one the pixelation remains obvious.

Pixelation can be reduced by (a) more gray levels in each pixel, and (b) more pixels per unit of area.  You can simulate this by taking off your glasses and standing way back!

In my electron diffraction experiments (not shown here) the contrast became comparable when the aggregate electron counts were similar: short exposure times for a large number of electrons per pulse, vs long exposure times when there were only a few electrons per pulse. The same applies for photons, IMHO.

The images here are borrowed from the Wikipedia article on the Double-slit Experiment; this one shows [single electron interference patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles), the same experiment at different time steps.

[image: Single electron double slit diffraction]

Comment: Thanks for fulfilling my request. I decided to up-vote your answer instead of checking it, 1) in the hope of hearing from more people personally experienced in the double-slit experiment, and 2) because I misunderstood your earlier comment. I thought you meant that in your personal experiments you compared full-intensity with very low intensity/one electron at-a-time, but now I see that you compared very low intensity with one electron at-a-time. Still invaluable nonetheless, and it'd be great if you'd make your data concerning it available.

Comment: @DavidReishi: You did understand my first comment; my results were not published, and I have so far been unable to find the images  - so I used published data that illustrates the contrast & pixelation problem.

Comment: I understand that that's published data from Wiki. What I mean is that you say you personally observed this: "...short exposure times for a large number of electrons per pulse, vs long exposure times when there were only a few electrons per pulse." The first sounds equivalent more to "very low light" than to "full light" in the sense of the original double-slit. In the latter, we're talking about constant bombardment with millions or more photons per second. Or was your large number of electrons per pulse mode actually along those lines too?

Comment: Less than 1,000 electrons per pulse, over a 200 micron diameter, diffracting through 10 nm of polycrystaline gold. Never more than 1 electron per path, repeated 1,000 times per second, for 60 seconds per exposure, for about 100 exposures. When the images are integrated you see as above. But I did the comparable with more electrons per pulse, and correspondingly fewer exposures. It's a well known result.

Comment: On another note, I suddenly realized that the image you posted above holds an important clue to answering my question.  Look at frame C.  If we were to count up the pixels in relation to the fringes, the location of which we know from the subsequent frames, it's pretty clear that we'd come up with a ratio of around 65:35 for those pixels in the "lit" areas: those pixels in the "dark" areas.  But that kind of ratio is _nothing like_ what we'd see in the full-light version.  That is to say, if done right we'd see in the full-light version much closer to a 100:0 ratio.

Comment: @DavidReishi: As mentioned previously, pixelation and the gray scale affect what you see. These images are essentially on/off for scaling, and each dot is a pixel.  See [classical wave optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Classical_wave-optics_formulation) for the mathematical form for the shape; it's a cosine squared times sinc squared. You can easily model this with your computer, and change the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as "clean" as you want - use sensors that only respond to a narrow wavelength (eg something so unlikely that it almost *must* be from your source...not IR for example!), set up your experiment so that the source will, statistically, emit a single photon every *day* or two to avoid the possibility that you're getting interference from the source "double tapping" the target, and so on.  Thing is, you can still, in principle get "noise" in the dark area. This is the nature of quantum mechanics. Unless you can set up your experiment to guarantee an absolutely zero probability of a photon striking the "dark area" then you will, given long enough, have the odd hit in the dark area. I'm not actually sure if this setup is possible - but what you can do is set it up so that you get a 5-sigma (or arbitrarily higher) chance of ensuring a dark area stays dark over any given timescale.

Comment: I might be wrong, and I found it surprising myself when I learned it, but it turns out that pretty much the whole world of double-slits, single-slits, interference and like has been take over by a very particular and very applied field: optics. What's surprising, however, is that optics barely gives a fig for the quantum theory of light, and deals exclusively in waves. And when you're dealing with waves the way optics does in the context of destructive interference, there's no probability involved. In certain areas the light will be out of phase to a certain degree, no ifs, ands or buts.

Comment: @DavidReishi  You are *way* off the track if you think that optics barely gives a fig for the quantum theory of light.  You are also *way* off the track when you say that there's no probability involved. Do you think that the choice of which pixel lights up is deterministic?  *Way* off the track.

Comment: I don't mean that there's no probability involved in what's happening with light; I mean that there's no probability involved in how the field of optics deals with interference. And I hold to what I said about optics barely giving a fig for the quantum theory of light...though perhaps I should be more specific and say Physical Optics. And it's no wonder really. What use could such an applied field dealing with light have of a theory that so flimsily explains the reality it deals in?

Comment: @DavidReishi It depends on what you are doing.  Sometimes you can ignore the quantum aspect.  I really don't understand what you are trying to say.  Perhaps lens designers don't give a fig about quantum optics, but *anyone* doing optics research has wave optics in his left hand and quantum optics in his right hand.  Concerning interference:  the wave amplitude *is* the probability of an interaction occurring.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that Physical Optics goes about its work, which one could say centers on interference, without ever resorting to notions of fields and modes "filling all space" and in which light itself is reduced to point-like probabilistic "excitations." To physical optics, light-waves exist in reality. And, yes, a light-wave's amplitude is tied to the probability of where its energy will land. But in the question at hand that's irrelevant, at least for optics, because destructive interference is about where the energy of light-waves will _not_ land.